# Passing Data between TableView in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have two tableView running in my project.I am trying to pass(copy) my first tableViewcell data to second tableView.I using tableView row action method to pass data.My partial code below...

**First VC:**

```
var tableView: UITableView!
var DataArray = ["Bus","Helicopter","Truck","Boat","Bicycle","Motorcycle","Plane","Train","Car","S    cooter","Caravan"]
var sendSelectedData = NSString()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

let copyAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.normal, title: "Pass Data") { (UITableViewRowAction, NSIndexPath) -> Void in

print("Button Pressed") // Xcode Console prints **Button Pressed** when swipe action performed.

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "send", sender: self)

 }

return [copyAction]
 }


func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "send", sender: self)
    // segue.destination as! tableController

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell =  tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)!
    self.sendSelectedData = (currentCell.textLabel?.text)! as String as NSString

    let viewController = segue.destination as! tableController
    viewController.labelcell = ([self.sendSelectedData as String])
    print(self.sendSelectedData)  // no result
}
```

**Second VC:**

```
var labelcell = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell


    cell.textLabel?.text = labelcell[indexPath.row] as? String

    tableView.reloadData()

    return cell
}
```

Above code looks like passing data to my second VC(segue).But, I am only getting a empty tableview..

Comment: Why are you calling `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "send", sender: nil)` inside prepare for segue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send data from TableView to DetailView Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430663/send-data-from-tableview-to-detailview-swift)

Comment: @Nirav D . Thanks. I changed sender to self. still no result..

Comment: @DavidSeek I already  looked at your link and i also seen similar questions  in the forum. all those questions only explained how to pass data to detailview controller not the TV.did you find anything wrong with my code....thanks

Comment: okay i'm having a look at it right now

Comment: it's swift3 isnt it?

Comment: @DavidSeek Swift 3... thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124722/discussion-between-david-seek-and-joe).

Comment: @DavidSeek   THIS PRINT WILL GET CALLED
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) at tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.

Comment: see the recent edit

Comment: so dude? you got it running? i edited my answer again to make it more clear

Comment: @DavidSeek  Thanks mate your code works great. appreciate your effort thanks....

Comment: glad to help you buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after testing it, it turns out, that you're using an incorrect `prepareForSegue` function. You are not using "prepareForSegue", you are **creating** a function called `prepareForSegue` - since the syntax has changed in Swift 3. This one will get called and you can pass data.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "send" {

        let selectedIndex = sender as! NSIndexPath
        let currentCell =  tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndex as IndexPath)! as! Cell
        self.sendSelectedData = (currentCell.label?.text)! as String as NSString

        print(self.sendSelectedData) // till here it worked for me - it is filled with my label.text
        // I don't know what this is "viewController.labelcell", so you have to to know how to go on from here on

        viewController.labelcell = ([self.sendSelectedData as String])           
    }
}
```

Also you need to pass the indexPath:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "send", sender: indexPath)
```

Exactly like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let copyAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.normal, title: "Pass Data") { (UITableViewRowAction, NSIndexPath) -> Void in

        print("editActionsForRowAt called") // Xcode Console prints **Button Pressed** when swipe action performed.
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "send", sender: indexPath)

    }

    return [copyAction]
}
```

This worked in my testing project.

Also beware: `Cell` is a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` I have created and label is an `UIOutlet` of a label element for my test project.