# Why is this out of index?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, segue

i am trying to call an array from my viewcontroller and then setting text from that array which contains objects. But when i perform the segue it only gives me an "Index out of range" I do not see what i have done wrong. I have also tried to use the self. everywhere in the call but it dosent seem to be the problem.

The variable movie is where i try to get only 1 movie from the array but the same problem persists. Have I done something wrong with my viewcontroller or do i need to pass a value in?

Detailsviewcontroller is the controller for the new view and the tableview, that is why i have created another class inside the file.

File: DetailsviewController

```
import UIKit
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITabBarDelegate { 

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



    var mainController = ViewController()

    var movie = ViewController().self.movieArray[0]





    var titles = ["Title", "Release Date","Genres","OverView"]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(movie)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titles.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DetailsCustomcell

        cell.detailTitle.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        if indexPath.row == 0{
        cell.detailContent.text = ""
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1{
            cell.detailContent.text = ""
        }
        if indexPath.row == 2{
            cell.detailContent.text = "Movie genre´s is not fixed yet"
        }
        if indexPath.row == 3{
            cell.detailContent.text = ""
        }
            return cell
    }





    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
class DetailsCustomcell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var detailTitle: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var detailContent: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: Consider that the two instances of `ViewController()` are different from each other and different from the `ViewController` instance in the storyboard or xib. That's the problem. You need the actual reference to the view controller.

Comment: What is the line `var mainController = ViewController()` for? It appears unused and what is the `ViewController` class? What does `var movie = ViewController().self.movieArray[0]` attempt to do? I guess this is the line causing the problem but to be clear please indicate which line is causing the exception and add the *full* error message to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you share data between view controllers and other objects in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734954/how-do-you-share-data-between-view-controllers-and-other-objects-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what this is:

```
var mainController = ViewController()
var movie = ViewController().self.movieArray[0]
```

Regardless, `ViewController()` instantiates a new object of that class.  At that point, it's very likely `movieArray` has never been initialized and has no objects in it.

Comment: Aha, didnt think of that! How do i specifically reference a viewcontroller then?

Comment: It really depends.  But my questioning would start with why do you need to get the 'movie' from this view controller's property instead of whatever data source populated the `movieArray` to begin with?

Comment: The reason as to why I need the movie is because i want to read the contents of the Array. The "movie" variable was just something i was testing out. I have a movieArray in my viewcontroller.swift where i do a get request then populate my movieArray with movieobjects. when the movie has been clicked on I wish to display the details of that specific movie.

Comment: Do a search for ways to pass data from master to detail view.  You'll get more tutorials and answers then you'll know what to do with.  Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430663/send-data-from-tableview-to-detailview-swift

Comment: Thank you so much!