# Recognize which tableviewcell is selected and pass value to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, cell

I'm trying to recognize which tableviewcell is selected and after that i want to get the label value of that cell and pass it to the next view controller. My cell has a Label value which is `string` and a Number value which is `Int`. I'm using a firebase database to get all that data.

**My code:**

```
import UIKit


class PlacesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
 //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var placesTableView: UITableView!
var places = [Places]()
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        // Loads data to cell.
        loadData()
    }
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {   
        //return the number of rows
        return places.count
    }
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "PlacesTableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PlacesTableViewCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PlacesTableView Cell.")
        }

        let place = places[indexPath.row]

        cell.placeLabel.text = place.name
        cell.ratingControl.rating = place.rating

        return cell

    }
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        print(places[indexPath.section])
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowCommentsTableViewController", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this thread to be useful [send-data-from-tableview-to-detailview-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430663/send-data-from-tableview-to-detailview-swift)

You have to create variable in destination view controller and store data in those Variable before Moving to Destination View controller.
This link will help you for this.

Comment: I understand what i have to do thank you for the thread! But i have a problem when i'm trying to override prepareForSegue func.

Comment: feel free to post question in stackoverflow.:)

Comment: i found it. it was a Swift 3 update code. `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` instead of what i used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let selectedPlace = places[indexPath.section]
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowCommentsTableViewController", sender: selectedPlace)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let selectedPlace = sender as? Places,
        let destViewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
        destViewController.place = selectedPlace
    }
}
```