# Swift 3 how to use cell objects data to another viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

basically, I'm trying to pass/use the cell instances (label.text) that I have already fetched from Firebase and assign it to the destination `chatViewController` variables

I believe I'm facing an issue with the segue ,, after debugging my code the segue do not pass the data this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { // 2
    return users.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.nameLblCell.text = users[indexPath.row].name
    cell.emailLblCell.text = users[indexPath.row].email
    cell.profilePictureCell.downloadImage(from: users[indexPath.row].proPicURL)
    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let instance = TableViewCell()
    let chatVc = segue.destination as? ChatViewController
    chatVc?.reciverImageVariable = instance.profilePictureCell.image!
    chatVc?.destinationEmail = instance.emailLblCell.text!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let userId = users[indexPath.row].id
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowChatView", sender: userId)

}
```

Comment: in prepareforSegue, access the selected cell as  

   let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() 
   let instance = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell

Comment: `let instance = TableViewCell()` you are creating a whole new cell. Instead, use `tableView.selectedIndexPath()` to retrieve the indexPath, and then use `user[thatIndexPathSelected.row]`.

Comment: you have try with navigation controller @OT AMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer ... the segue.destinationViewController will be a UINavigationViewController if ChatViewController is embedded in it's own UINavigationController then i followed along with @Pankaj with link he sent me ([Send data from TableView to DetailView Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430663/send-data-from-tableview-to-detailview-swift)) so final result as follow:

```
var valueToPass:String! // #1 i added this one first 

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as! TableViewCell

    valueToPass = currentCell.emailLblCell.text

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowChatView", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // #2 used if let as? UINavigationController

    if let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
        let destinationVC = navigationController.topViewController as? ChatViewController
        destinationVC?.destinationEmail = valueToPass
    }
```

Comment: @Pankaj thanks for the link you share in the comment it was part of final result

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRow(at: indexPath)` will give you respective cell values

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        print(cell.myTextField.text)
    }
```

If you have `UITableViewCell` (predefined) use -

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        print(cell?.textLabel?.text)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store tableview selected index in another variable or you can directly use tablview's selected index property. simple using that you can get selected cell's instance. simple change one lien in your preparForSegue method.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  let instance = tableView.cellForRow(at: tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow) 
  let chatVc = segue.destination as? ChatViewController
  chatVc?.reciverImageVariable = instance.profilePictureCell.image!
  chatVc?.destinationEmail = instance.emailLblCell.text!
}
```

Comment: i got an error 'has no memebr type' after force unwrapping this: let instance = tableView.cellForRow(at: tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow)

Comment: have you unwrapped cell ? let newCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!) i have tested this and i can print cell value too.

Comment: after that i followed xcode and i got the syntax error

Comment: okay you don't need to pass data from tableView cell, just use indexPath.row in did select method. this is also helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430663/send-data-from-tableview-to-detailview-swift

Comment: so after that what really happens instance. doesnt auto complete to emailLblCell.text or doesnt recognize it

Answer (score 0):

Why are you getting data from `tableviewcell` you can get data from main object `users`.

```
var selectedUserIndex = 0   

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let chatVc = segue.destination as? ChatViewController
    chatVc?.destinationEmail = users[selectedUserIndex].email
    chatVc?.reciverImageVariable = users[selectedUserIndex].proPicURL //again load from url in ChatViewController
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedUserIndex = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowChatView", sender: userId)    
}
```

Comment: I recommend load image in next screen from url, because it is possible you have tapped on the cell, but the image was not loaded in that situation image will pass nil.

Comment: i used your solutions no build errors so far but when i print the value (email, imgStr) nothing appears i think it doesnt pass the data .... in the chatviewcontoller my variables are:   var destinationEmail = String()
    var reciverImageVariable = String() so i test it using print(destinationEmail) in the viewDidload()

Comment: print variable into prepareForSegue method.

Comment: print(chatVc?.destinationEmail)

Comment: i got nil,,,, actually i intended to print it in the second view controller  (chatVC) but nothing shows

Comment: i know you want to print into chatVC. now write this code into prepareForSegue method
print(users[selectedUserIndex].email)

Comment: @OTAMD do one thing, take one var like int or NSInteger and store indexPath.row in that var when you click on tableview cell. now in prepareForSegue method use that var and get selected object from your array and print that. if you successfully print out that data then pass that data to next viewController.  print this one  users[selectedUserIndex] , also add structure of your array so we can check it.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya yes you have done that but still he is not able to print that so need to check array structure

Comment: @PramodTapaniya i finally got the result printed in the debug area when segue is performed but its not printed in the chatVC so can be able to use ?

Comment: this is my user data:
`internal class User {
    internal let id: String
    internal let name: String
    internal let email: String
    internal let proPicURL: String
    
    init(id: String, name: String, email:String, proPicURL:String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.proPicURL = proPicURL
    }
}`

Comment: check segue destination viewcontroller and it's class, name of segue.

Comment: @OTAMD than accept as a correct answer. So other developers can easily find a solution. :)