# programmatically changing views with Swift - not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code which is intended to change views.  This code is executed when my 'UITableViewRowAction' is selected and is intended to navigate to a different UITableViewController.  However, I am getting the error below and I do not understand what I am doing incorrectly.

```
 let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let selectFolderViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SaveArticleTableViewController") as! SaveArticleTableViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(selectFolderViewController, animated: true)
```

The error that i am getting in the console is:

```
 Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x106f5c898) to 'lifesci_PubMed.SaveArticleTableViewController' (0x104dbb658).
```

All my ViewControllers are embedded within a Navigation Controller

Comment: I would encourage you to call the class simply **"SelectArticle"**.  Whatever you call the Class, you **>>>MUST<<<** call the variable the same thing, but just lower case for the first letter.  So, "selectArticle = instantiate(etc...) as! SelectArticle"

Comment: I would encourage you to simply **not use** navigation controllers.  They are kind of .. silly.  It really just causes problems when you're learning the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually quite descriptive here:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' to 'SaveArticleTableViewController'
```

At first I thought that this was because your view controller `SaveArticleTableViewController` is not actually set with a custom class. If you're using Interface Builder, make sure you've set the class type in the view controller's property inspector:

[image]

If you're doing it in code, make sure your custom class is inheriting properly.

But taking a leap of a guess, your target is "UINavigationController", but your custom class name that it's trying to cast to suggests that your target is a table view "SaveArticleTableViewController". Moreover, I'd bet that this is the tableview that is the *source* not the destination. I'd double check that you're actually instantiating the right view controller - typically you'd name this something like "SaveArticleDetailViewController", or guessing by your code, maybe it's "SelectFolderViewController", but that's up to you.

For example:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let selectFolderViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectFolderViewController") as! SelectFolderViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(selectFolderViewController, animated: true)
```

This also requires that you set `self.navigationController` to the containing nav controller.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct.  As a side question.  Since i am using UITableViewRowAction and the function 'func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?' to move to another ViewController, I  can't figure out how to transfer data from the initial table row to the new viewController - as I cannot really use Segues in this scenario - at least I do not believe I can.  Would you be able to advise?

Comment: No, you must ask a new separate question.

Comment: Fwiw, there are a ton of answers on SO already for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430663/send-data-from-tableview-to-detailview-swift

Comment: You can easily use a segue; just send the appropriate object as the `sender`

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that you have not properly set the custom class of the view controller in Storyboard.  Here's an image ...

[image]

You would type "SaveArticleTableViewController" in that slot.

It's quite possible you have other problem as well, but that will get you going.