# Not receiving data in detailview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, detailview

I have a TableView that when the user clicks it needs to show a detail view displaying the name of the row it clicked. I populate the tableView using a Json call but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is my bits of code of ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var valueToPass:String!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    // Instantiate animals class
    var items = [animalObject]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        addDummyData()
    }

    func addDummyData() {
        RestManager.sharedInstance.getRandomUser(onCompletion: {(json) in
            if let results = json.array {
                for entry in results {
                    self.items.append(animalObject(json: entry))
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.sync{
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier") as! CustomTableViewCell!

        let animal = self.items[indexPath.row]

        cell?.label.text = animal.name

        return cell! //4.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

        // Get Cell Label
//        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        var currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
        print(currentCell.textLabel?.text)
        valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel?.text
        print(valueToPass)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailView", sender: indexPath)
    }

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

        if (segue.identifier == "detailView") {
            // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
            let viewController = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
            // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
            viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
        }
    }

}
```

and my detailView only has the following info

```
@IBOutlet weak var tooPass: UILabel!
var passedValue: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("DETAILS")
    print(passedValue)
    tooPass.text = passedValue
}
```

I'm not sure if the preparedToSegue is firing a little bit earlier because my terminal looks like this:
[image]

I used as a reference the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430663/send-data-from-tableview-to-detailview-swift) any guidance will be appreciated

Comment: You don't need `let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!`. You already have access to `indexPath` in `didSelectRow` method. Remove this line and see what happens

Comment: @Malik It didnt change anything

Comment: can you share your `cellForRow` method?

Comment: check value for currentCell, or currentCell.textLabel..

Comment: It's not a method is a predefined one by swift @Malik

Comment: @user2737948 Are you using static cells?

Comment: If I print currentCell.textLabel returns a nil value @Skywalker

Comment: and that is why your value isn't being passed.. because its nil where you pass it.. how do you populate your tableview in first view controller?

Comment: I just edit my answer to show my complete ViewController @Skywalker

Comment: you should have an array where you have text you use to fill in the text label inside cellForRow method.. use that array to access the value to pass instead of the cellForRow method

Answer (score 1):

Try this for `didSelectRowAt` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        valueToPass = self.items[indexPath.row]
        print(valueToPass)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailView", sender: indexPath)
    }
```

Just pass the entire item in the items array.

Make the DetailViewController's passed item of type item. Then just access `item.whateverPropertyRequired`.

Comment: It works but I just read my question and I didnt explain very well what I'm trying to accomplish, once the user clicks the cell I need to pass the complete cell because inside the details view I need to display the .name and .species. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @user2737948 You should have the name and species inside the self.items array I believe. Just pass the entire item in the array

Comment: It keeps receiving a nil value when I unwrapped it inside the detailViewController, I made the proper changed from String to animalObject. The error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @user2737948 Put a breakpoint inside prepareForSegue and see if value being passed is not nil.. and check inside viewDidLoad of detail view controller also

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `cellForRow` method, you are casting your cell to `CustomTableViewCell` type while in your `didSelectRow`, you are casting it as `UITableViewCell`. Change

```
var currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
```

in your `didSelectRow` to

```
var currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as CustomTableViewCell
```

Comment: its better to access the array than to call cellForRow method from within the didSelectRowAt method

Answer (score 0):

Good approach here is to use view model. Create model which contains your items and data associated with them. And at segue pass your data model. It’s bad coding, getting data right from cell on didSelect method, unless some ui working on that cell